# howto to join "only" values of a an element of a dictionary of two elements in python list

Tags: python, dictionary

Consider a list with dictionary members
as follows:

```
txt1 = {
  'k1': 'val1',
  'k2': 14,
  'k3': 5,
  'A':[
       {'i1': 0, 'i2': 'value1'}, 
       {'i1': 2, 'i2': 'value2'}, 
       {'i1': 6, 'i2': 'value3'}, 
       {'i1': 9, 'i2': 'value4'}, 
       {'i1': 11, 'i2': 'value5'}
       ],
  't': 4,
  'l':-1,
  'a': 'G',
  'h': [],
  'd':[],
  'tp':[]}
```

What is the best way of getting a string composed of "value1 value2...value5".  I know how to do it thru a loop?  But I am wondering if there are short cuts to d so.
Thanks for your help

Comment: How would you define "best way"?

Comment: `[a['i2'] for a in txt1['A']]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list comprehension like:

```
value_list = [a['i2'] for a in txt1['A']]
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution is shorter than mine.  I also thought since the format is json compatible there maybe better way of doing it.  But I am set with the responses.

Answer (score 1):

```
ans = [d['i2'] for d in txt1['A']]
print(' '.join(ans))
```

Output: `value1 value2 value3 value4 value5`
I hope that's you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [one_dict['i2'] for one_dict in txt1['A']]

>>> ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5']
```

[For more information on shorthands please refer to this guide on python generator expressions.](https://www.pythontutorial.net/advanced-python/python-generator-expressions/)